# Splitting a bimodel Distribution

Tags: r, distribution

My data has a biomodal distribution (histogram below) and I would like to find a way to split it.
I can obviously do this by eye, but I have hundreds of similar data sets so i want to automate this.

[image: histogram of my data]

```
> dput(dat[1:100])
structure(c(6.68586094706836, 0, 6.3578422665081, 6.3578422665081, 
6.61338421837956, 0, 0, 6.39859493453521, 6.4377516497364, 0, 
0, 0, 6.24027584517077, 6.46302945692067, 6.37842618365159, 6.30809844150953, 
0, 6.44413125670044, 0, 0, 6.24027584517077, 6.58617165485467, 
0, 0, 6.28599809450886, 6.45676965557216, 0, 0, 6.43133108193348, 
6.45047042214418, 0, 6.49375383985169, 0, 6.34388043412633, 6.56385552653213, 
6.94022246911964, 6.2709884318583, 6.78105762593618, 0, 6.32256523992728, 
6.43133108193348, 6.36475075685191, 0, 6.5410299991899, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 6.75343791859778, 6.34388043412633, 0, 0, 0, 6.26339826259162, 
0, 6.37842618365159, 0, 6.45047042214418, 6.34388043412633, 0, 
0, 6.84694313958538, 6.83410873881384, 6.62406522779989, 0, 6.4377516497364, 
6.43133108193348, 0, 6.51767127291227, 6.46925031679577, 0, 6.67582322163485, 
6.39859493453521, 6.90875477931522, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.31535800152233, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0))
```

I am thought to use mixture models and am using the following code I found.

```
library(mixtools)

simulate <- function(lambda=0.3, mu=c(0, 4), sd=c(1, 1), n.obs=10^5) {
x1 <- rnorm(n.obs, mu[1], sd[1])
x2 <- rnorm(n.obs, mu[2], sd[2])    
return(ifelse(runif(n.obs) < lambda, x1, x2))
}
x <- simulate()
model <- normalmixEM(x=x, k=2)
index.lower <- which.min(model$mu)  # Index of component with lower mean

find.cutoff <- function(proba=0.5, i=index.lower) {
## Cutoff such that Pr[drawn from bad component] == proba
f <- function(x) {
    proba - (model$lambda[i]*dnorm(x, model$mu[i], model$sigma[i]) /
                 (model$lambda[1]*dnorm(x, model$mu[1], model$sigma[1]) + model$lambda[2]*dnorm(x, model$mu[2], model$sigma[2])))
    }
    return(uniroot(f=f, lower=-10, upper=10)$root)  # Careful with division by zero if changing lower and upper
}

cutoffs <- c(find.cutoff(proba=0.5), find.cutoff(proba=0.75))  # Around c(1.8, 1.5)

hist(x)
abline(v=cutoffs, col=c("red", "blue"), lty=2)
```

However, I am getting this error.

```
One of the variances is going to zero;  trying new starting values.
```

I guess this is because their is no variance in the samples that are 0, there is only variance in the samples with values around 6. (note the peak at lower values wont always be zero, but often will be)

Is there any way around this, or any other approach that I should be using?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can take the output of `hist` and use something like `pastecs::turnpoints` on the output.

```
foo<-hist(your_data,your_arguments)
mins <- turnpoints(foo$values)$pits
```

Then "back up" and identify the `foo$breaks` or `foo$mids` which correspond to that minimum.